# How to share a photo on facebook wall from a website?

Tags: facebook

Hi guys I am working on a project:

the client's goal is to let user simply share the photo on their facebook wall with some fixed message. and the project is simply a website, no login is needed, user will just come to the machine and take a photo and click to share to facebook account, of course user will be required for permission to let my website to access his fb account.

so what should it be? simply the like button? or maybe something more tricky like using the Graph API? I am still reading on it at the moment since I am really new to Facebook. Please give some hint.

By the way I may use wordpress for my backend

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you will need user to give your app permission to post on the wall, next after the photo is taken you will need to post it on user's wall using Graph API (you can find out how to do that [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos))